# Android Tablet Application Development

Tags: android, android-emulator

I typically use Eclipse with the Android Plug-in for mobile phone development. I was wondering how I could use this existing setup to develop and test Android Tablet applications. Anyone have any suggestions/experience with this? Any alternatives for testing?

Update:
http://www.droidsector.com/blog/2010/05/21/how-to-emulate-a-tablet-in-android-sdk-2-2/

:-)

Comment: You should answer your own question so that people can up-vote it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be creating anew avd config to specify the tablet screen size, memory constraints, SDcard size, etc. I believe that most of that can be achieved by just creating a new avd and changing the parameters in avd manager. Although You may also have to create a tablet skin to go with the AVd you created.  I would first check with the tablet OEM and see if they already have create a SDK addon for that purpose.

Comment: Fantastic. I am very excited about this. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, I would advise designing your app layout proportionally rather than with specific length. It would work both ways and would be two birds one stone.  All of my phone apps can be installed to the tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab) from either the Android Market AND be tested directly from Eclipse. You can run the apps on either the phone or the tablet devices directly from Eclipse to visualize the differences. Proportion wins.